# Remove text between parentheses in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, regexp-replace

Looking for RegExp to remove text between parentheses in dart/flutter. For example

Input...

```
Test Message (To Be removed)
```

Output

```
Test Message
```

```
String str = "Test Message (To Be removed)";
str.replaceAll(RegExp(<regular-expression>), '');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi You can use this RegExp

```
String str = "Test Message (To Be removed)";
var test = str.replaceAll(RegExp('\\(.*?\\)'), '');
print(test);
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove completely without replacing with a empty string?

Comment: No, There is only one way to remove this. What is your string?

Comment: It was more to do with what I was doing after. Not to worry, simple workaround :)

Comment: This regex assumes the there aren't any double parentheses, like (text (more text)). When that happens it breaks

Answer (score 0):

Another RegExp

```
RegExp(r'\((.*)\)')
```